# Magento 2.3.2 - Need DynamicRows instead of MultiSelect

Tags: php, magento2

```
$fieldset->addField('post_code', 'multiselect', array(
      'label'     => 'Post Code',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'post_code',
      'values' => array(
              array('value'=>30002,'label'=>'30002'),
              array('value'=>30003,'label'=>'30003'),
              array('value'=>30004,'label'=>'30004'),
              array('value'=>30005,'label'=>'30005'),
              array('value'=>30006,'label'=>'30006'),
              array('value'=>30007,'label'=>'30007'),
              array('value'=>30008,'label'=>'30008'),
              array('value'=>30009,'label'=>'30009'),
      )
    ));
```

This is my block code. I am not using any Template. Is there any way to change this multiselect into DynamicRows Component? I am using Magento2.3.2

I have added My page's xml code also

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
            <css src="Traders_Grid::multi.css" />
            <script src="Traders_Grid::multi.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Traders\Grid\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AddRow" name="add_row" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```